# Hyperlink on update button (ajax json)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm trying to make an update button on a table that i make with ajax json, there is a problem that i can't put id_news attribute on the  tag along with the target link. I tried put it next to the target link, but it doesn't work, and even the tables doesn't show anything, is there any way to make it work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  display_data_info();

  function display_data_info() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'ajax',
      url: '<?php echo base_url()?>/information/data_read_info',
      async: false,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data) {
        var html = '';
        var i;
        var no;
        var id_news;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          no = +1;
          html += '<tr>' +
            '<td>' +
            no +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            data[i].news_title +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            data[i].news_info +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
            data[i].news_status +
            '</td>' +
            '<td><a href="<?php echo site_url("information/display_update_info/".data[i].id_news); ?>" class="btn btn-app">' +
            '<i class="fas fa-edit"></i> ' +
            '</a>' +

            '</td>' +
            '</tr>';
        }
        $('#show_data_info').html(html);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Load the page in the browser and see the source (Ctrl+U) and you'll see where's the mistakes.

Comment: What does `data` has in it ,post that as well .

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple typos and mistakes here:

- In the first php part, put a `;` after base_url()
- You are not initializing `no` before you do `no += 1`
- Instead of `no += 1` you do `no = +1` (which may accidentally overcome the previous error but it's probably not what you want)
- In the `<td><a href=....` line you are mixing up single and double quotes
- In that same line, your javascript variable is inside PHP. `data[i].id_news` does not exist in PHP scope.

Check your web console and PHP error log, there will be several errors.

Comment: thanks for the correction, for var no, i do initilize it first. seems like there's no way to get the id_news value to put it on the last segment of the link in this way, i will just find another way to make my update module